# How to retrieve original iOS distribution certificate from original Mac to fix "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificates"

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I'm kind of new in this Apple certificate and provisioning galore, and also don't really understand much about keychain. What I've learn from this error is that I need to get the original team certificate from the original Mac which create the team certificate, export it, and import it to mine.

The only problem is: which certificate? I have my own team dev certificate, so I guess I want to draw parallel comparison. But when I tried to open my own the keychain, I'm presented with tons of keys that I don't know which one to export. And now, I need to give instruction to people on the remote location on which certificate to export, but how I'm supposed to give instruction if I myself don't know certificate with which name to export? The other guy is also don't know so much about certificates too.

All this time, I always use "reset" or "revoke" certificate to resolve this problem. But I know that's not the correct way because the certificate on the other computer will be invalid then. Because this is a different team, I cannot use the "revoke" tricks here. How can I do this the correct way and point the other guy which one to export? What is the hints that usually give signs that this is the correct certificate to export?

Comment: try downloading all the provisioning profiles in Xcode Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details.

Comment: @enigma that doesn't work. the other team finally has a tech support helps them to export and give it to me. In the end, they give me .p12 and .pem file to create the public/private key pair, and the distribution provisioning file. But they created this anew, not from the same old team, even though it's from the same account. I don't know how they do this.